# Don't automatically terminate git diff if changes are on one page

Tags: git, bash, less-unix

If I run `git diff`, and my changes are less than one page, the command will automatically exit. This is undesired because this is in a script and I immediately call `git commit` afterwards. This causes single page changelogs to be missed.

My first thought would be to pipe the differences into `less`, but this causes no differences changelogs to display an empty screen (which requires a `q` press to exit). Here is the command I'm using: `git diff --color=always | less`.

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a `.lessrc` file around somewhere? `less` should not be automatically existing by default. (For example, the `-e` and `-E` options to `less` provide the behavior you are reporting.)

Comment: Ignore the above comment and see my answer; I have an environment variable set that prevents `less` from exiting early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script to do the job:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

num_lines=$(git diff | wc -l)

if [ $num_lines -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "No changes"
else
  git diff --color=always | less --raw-control-chars
fi
```

Or, here's a one-liner originally based on [@Phillip's comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39475087/dont-automatically-terminate-git-diff-if-changes-are-on-one-page/39475282?noredirect=1#comment66270003_39475282), with some fixes thanks to [@tripleee](//stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee):

```bash
git diff --color=always | (IFS=$'\n' read -r A; if [ -n "$A" ]; then (printf '%s\n' "$A"; cat) | less --raw-control-chars; else echo "No changes"; fi)
```

The one-liner has the advantage of only running `git diff` once for better performance.

Some explanation per [@tripleee's comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39475087/dont-automatically-terminate-git-diff-if-changes-are-on-one-page/39475282#comment66270944_39475282):

> You should properly use `read -r` to not unintentionally mangle the first line. This will still mangle leading or trailing whitespace. You can fix that with `IFS=$'\n'` before `read -r`. `echo` might throw an error or behave strangely if the first line starts with a dash (which looks to `echo` like an option argument) -- use `printf '%s\n' "$A"` instead to avoid that.

In both cases, the `--raw-control-chars` option (short version `-r`) passed to `less` will cause the colors to show up correctly.

Comment: This can be optimized such that you only have to `diff` once: If you run `git diff` with the `PAGER` environment variable set to a similar bash script: `PAGER="read A; if [ -n '\$A' ]; then echo '\$A'; less; fi" git diff`.

Comment: @Phillip I wouldn't consider exploiting the pager variable for business logic an optimization, but this is a nice hack for Code Golf.

Comment: The optimization is to run `git diff` only once, rather than twice, and dynamically decide whether to run `less` or not. `git diff | (read A; if [ -n "$A" ]; then echo "$A"; less; fi)` would work just as well.

Comment: Isn't there a missing `else` before the `less` call, @Phillip?

Comment: Thanks @Phillip! Added a one-liner based on yours to my answer.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Nope, that's intentional. If there is any output, then run `less`, else just exit.

Comment: Long term Linux user here and I just learned a whole bunch on bash usage :-)

Comment: @ScottWeldon Your version of the one-liner drops the first line of the `git diff` output!

Comment: @Phillip: I edited to match your version, but that still has a problem: the first line is printed to the terminal, and *everything else* is sent to `less`.

Comment: You should properly use `read -r` to not unintentionally mangle the first line.  This will still mangle leading or trailing whitespace.  You can fix that with `IFS=$'\n'` before `read -r`.  `echo` might throw an error or behave strangely if the first line starts with a dash (which looks to `echo` like an option argument) -- use `printf '%s\n' "$A"` instead to avoid that.

Comment: @tripleee: Adding `-r` to the `read` command doesn't seem to help with the line mangling. The first line is still being printed to the terminal instead of being sent to `less`.

Comment: The `-r`option very specifically disables some legacy behavior with backslashes.  The problem with losing the first line is unrelated; it seems to be the placement of the parenthesis -- the answer completely lacks a closing parenthesis.  I would go with `... | IFS=$'\n' read -r; if [ -n "$REPLY" ]; then ( echo "$REPLY"; cat ) | less; fi`

Comment: @tripleee: Ah okay, I thought you were responding to my last comment. Missing parenthesis was a typo; fixed.

Comment: Oh and I forgot my own `printf` advice, sorry! Duh.

Comment: But if you want the output from that to be sent to `less`, it needs to be part of that pipeline.  That's why you need parens; before `less`.

Comment: @tripleee: I'm still having some issues. If you're willing to help me debug, then let us [continue this discussion in chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123288/discussion-between-scott-weldon-and-tripleee).

Comment: @ScottWeldon Yep, I meant to pipe the `echo` output to `less` as well, like @tripleee did lateron. Sorry.

Comment: I was using this in a makefile, so I had to move it to it's own script file to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is `less` being invoked with the `-F` option by `git`. Normally, `less` uses any options stored in the environment variable `LESS`. If that variable is not set, `git` automatically sets it to `FRX` before running `less`. (That is, without a value for `LESS`, `git` effectively is running `less -FRX`.)

One way to override this is to add the following to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[core]
    pager = less -+F
```

If `LESS` is not set, then the preceding configuration causes `less` to be called as

```
LESS=FRX less -+F
```

meaning the `-F` option is first enabled via the environment in which `less` runs, then immediately *disabled* from the command line.

(In my comment to your question, I indicated that `less` should not be exiting early. I observed that because I in fact have `LESS=X` in my environment, so I did not have `-F` added automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

Provided `less` is your pager, you can affect this behavior for all invocations with

```
export LESS=-E
```

This will override any previous value.  To avoid that, and instead add `-E` to the front of the other options, use

```
LESS=-E"${LESS#-}"
```

To affect it for just `git`, maybe something like

```
alias git='LESS=-E"${LESS#-}" git'
```

(This is `sh` syntax, i.e. should be suitable for Bash, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc.)

For other pagers, similar approaches should work.  You just need to find the option which affects this behavior.

Comment: In practice, I have already used this to add `LESS=-r` to settings when running `git` in order to get color codes to work correctly.  Dunno what's up with that, but it seems to be a problem on all platforms where I use `git`.